# TypeScript + Angular dynamic Imports module build failed

Tags: angular, typescript, importerror

I am working on a public personal project : https://github.com/chdelucia/hack

I would like to import some modules dynacmically. When I code it in a plain string is working as expected:

```
const a = await import(`../data/ctfbanditi`);
```

But when I try it with variables like this:

```
let b = 'ctfbanditi';
const a = await import(`../data/${b}`);
```

I get the following error:

> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
> Error: C:\MYlocalpath\data\ctfbanditi.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation.
> Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property. at ivy\loader.js

I have read some similar issues were caused by miss spelling errors like lowercase uppercase and so on, but I think is no my case.

The idea is to have some function where got a name attribute and read the specific module like that:

```
  async getBlogHtmlbyId(name: string): Promise<string> {
    let code= '';
    const a = await import(`../data/${name}`);
    return code;
  }
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, I just tried this with my project (also has dynamic imports), and it won't compile.

Comment: Why you just create string before import, I mean you can do like this: let module = `../data/${name}` and the pass module to import:   const a = await import(module); I do not try it I just suggest

Comment: @MahdiRezazadeh that approach has the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this problem is adding the ts modules on **tsconfig.app.json**

In my case all my modules i want to import dynacmically are stored on a folder /data/. So i added **"src/data/*.ts"** on include section like this:

```
    /* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts",
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts",
    "src/data/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

And on the service side:

```
  async getBlogHtmlbyId(fileName: string): Promise<string> {
    const code = await import(`../data/${fileName}`);
    return code?.blog || '';
  }
```